# Delete entities without loading them into memory

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework Core I have the following Entity:

```
public class File {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Byte[] Content { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a list of files ids which I need to delete:

```
List<Int32> ids = new List<Int32> { 4, 6, 8 }; // Ids example
```

How can I delete the 3 files without loading each file Content property?

```
_context.Files.Remove(??);
```

I do not want to load each file Content property as it is big in size.

Comment: this missing feature is tracked here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/795

Answer (score 32, accepted):

EF Core 7 now supports [ExecuteUpdate and ExecuteDelete (Bulk updates)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates):

```cs
// Delete all Tags (BE CAREFUL!)
await context.Tags.ExecuteDeleteAsync();

// Delete Tags with a condition
await context.Tags.Where(t => t.Text.Contains(".NET")).ExecuteDeleteAsync();
```

The equivalent SQL queries are:

```sql
DELETE FROM [t]
FROM [Tags] AS [t]

DELETE FROM [t]
FROM [Tags] AS [t]
WHERE [t].[Text] LIKE N'%.NET%'
```

Comment: Although `ExecuteDeleteAsync()` does the trick, however, be aware that `ExecuteDeleteAsync()` doesn't respect the Change Tracker and transactional `SaveChanges()`. In other words, it is not reversible once you do the `ExecuteDeleteAsync()` unless you implement a transaction mechanism. Thus, you have to create a [transaction][1] manually and handle the commit/rollback. As a workaround, use the @Matt's suggestion in which he instantiates a fake entity to pass to the `Remove()` method.  

[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions

Answer (score 29):

If you are sure the all Ids exist in the database and context does not contain (is not tracking) other entities with the same keys, you can use simple fake (*stub*) entities:

```
_context.RemoveRange(ids.Select(id => new File { Id = id }));
```

To avoid problem with non existing ids, you can get the existing ids from the database:

```
var existingIds = _context.Files.Where(f => ids.Contains(f.Id)).Select(f => f.Id).ToList();

_context.RemoveRange(existingIds.Select(id => new File { Id = id }));
```

To avoid tracking entity problem, you can use the `FindTracked` custom extension method from my answer to [Delete loaded and unloaded objects by ID in EntityFrameworkCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813464/delete-loaded-and-unloaded-objects-by-id-in-entityframeworkcore/47821015#47821015) and combine it with any of the above.

```
var existingIds = _context.Files.Where(f => ids.Contains(f.Id)).Select(f => f.Id).ToList();

_context.RemoveRange(
    existingIds.Select(id => _context.FindTracked(id) ?? new File { Id = id }));
```

Comment: `.ToList();` != "without loading them into memory"

Comment: `RemoveRange` fires as many executions as there are elements in the list. EF is good only for demos

Comment: @Toolkit (1) Loading PKs is not the same as loading full records. (2) EF indeed is not good for mass modifications

Comment: This is not a proper approach. Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53977262/631527

Comment: @Toolkit Not a "proper"? I don't need to check your approach. I'm aware of  that **3rd party** library, but it's not EF **out of the box** solution (in fact it bypasses EF). One can use plain SQL with the same effect. This doesn't mean the library is not good - it is, just it isn't "standard" solution, and some people don't want/are not allowed to use 3rd party libraries. Anyway, it's your right to have a different opinion, just don't tell me what is "proper".

Comment: and where did it say it should be "out of the box"? Anyway  `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` is out of the box. And it doesn't "bypass EF", what does it even mean

Answer (score 25):

Entity tracking can work manually and without any database call, so long as you can uniquely identify the entity.

What you are after is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#handling-deletes).

```
var entity = new EntityModel {
   Id = yourId
};

var entry = context.Entry(entity);
entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Which is the same as ...

```
var entity = new EntityModel {
   Id = yourId
};

var entry = context.Entry(entity);
context.Remove(entry);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This is the only way I know, but I would really like if it could do it from a Queryable.

Comment: @Ablue I can't believe I've used EF for so long and just learned this trick. Absolutely  brilliant. I'd buy you a drink right now if I knew how to send you money.

Answer (score 6):

Install **Z.EntityFramework.Extensions** or **Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore** package according to your **dotnet version**.

Then use DeleteFromQuery() or DeleteFromQueryAsync() method after your **query**.

```
await _dbContext.MyTable.Where(w => w.TypeId == 5).DeleteFromQueryAsync();
```

DeleteFromQuery gives you access to **directly** execute a DELETE statement in the database and provide a HUGE performance improvement **without** select and load objects.

Performance Comparisons :

Operations :    1,000 Entitie - 2,000 Entities -    5,000 Entities

SaveChange :    1,000 ms    -    2,000 ms   -    5,000 ms

DeleteFromQuery : 1 ms   -   1 ms      -     1 ms

Comment: bad extension, does not work with intellisense

Comment: `Z.EntityFramework` is not free. https://entityframework-extensions.net/licensing

Answer (score 1):

from **EF Core 7** or later

```
context.Blogs.Where(b => b.Rating < 3).ExecuteDelete();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete#executedelete

Comment: Please don't repeat an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75243620/861716) when it's helpful. It's merely noise.

Answer (score -5):

You can try [EntityFramework-Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus) and `Database.BeginTransaction()`

```
var db = new YourDbContext();
var dbContextTransaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction();
ctx.Users.Where(x => x.LastLoginDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2)).Delete();
//some other DB actions 
db.SaveChanges();
dbContextTransaction.Commit();
```

This way Delete is committed with the transaction

Update - it is now a paid version, thus the downvotes I guess

Comment: internally it uses raw SQL code, see https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/blob/master/src/shared/Z.EF.Plus.BatchDelete.Shared/BatchDelete.cs

Comment: the library is also mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/